# update quantity of product in database with java

Tags: java, swing

I'm building a supermarket system and I want to update quantity in stock when user sell from this product, I wrote this function `

```
    public String setqty(String bar){
    String qty = "SELECT SUM(QTY) FROM sales_product WHERE barcode = '"+bar+"'";
    int quantity = Integer.parseInt(qty);
    String sql = "update product set Qty = Qty - " + quantity + " where Barcode = " + bar;
    String str = (String) db.database.getTableData(sql).items[0][0];
    
    return str;
}`
```

but when I try to run it I get these errors

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "SELECT SUM(QTY) FROM sales_product WHERE barcode= '12345'"`

How can I resolve that Error

Comment: You run the `qty` query with a `db.database.getTableData(qty)` before trying to parse the result. Would be my guess.

Comment: Neither phpmyadmin nor mysql-workbench seem to be appropriate here.

Comment: On your update statement, you may need to add single-quotes around the variable bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code you are parsing a sql string with Integer.parseInt. You need to call the database inbetween

```
String qtySQL = "SELECT SUM(QTY) FROM sales_product WHERE barcode = '"+bar+"'";
String qty = (String) db.database.getTableData(qtySQL).items[0][0] //Now holding the value of sum(qty), if I got the syntax right
int quantity = Integer.parseInt(qty);
String sql = "update product set Qty = Qty - " + quantity + " where Barcode = " + bar;
String str = (String) db.database.getTableData(sql).items[0][0];

return str;
```

Comment: how can I call database ? I've already create connection in the code in path db.database.getTableData() .

Comment: Like you did with the update sql. I am not familiar with the right syntax, but maybe something like this: String qty = (String) db.database.getTableData(qtySQL).items[0][0];

Comment: You need to "ask" the database twice. First for getting the qty and then for getting the update result. You only call the database for getting the update done for you, but you did not make a database call for getting the qty. I updated the answer for you to see.

Comment: I tried that but I get Error message which say "Can not manipulation statements with executeQuery()"

Comment: Maybe I can check it for you. I do not know the package "db.database" and the class "getTableDate". Please give me a reference to the library you are using here.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/MohamedHossam933/a62d27e61af0adabcbab3ea1af730cde

this github link which I wrote in it the code for method getTableData and another class called Table which I used also in code

Comment: You are getting the exception for the second query because you need to call stmt.executeUpdate for an update statement. But with getTableDate you are calling only stmt.executeQuery, what is not working for an update statement.

Comment: Nice to hear that. It would be great if you could then mark the question as answered. Thanks!